# Find contents in files and open with Text Wrangler

Tags: bash

I am attempting to write a bash script that opens a file when a specific script is found in a file list.  The end goal is to take each line item in (search-list.txt), search all the files and open it in TextWrangler if it matches the term.

The files list (search-list.txt)

```
3.1.3.2
3.1.4.2
4.1.3.1
4.1.4.1
4.1.5.1
4.2.1.1
4.2.2.1
5.1.6.1
```

Script

```
#!/bin/bash

cat ./search-list.txt |  while read output

    do

        for f in $(find ./content/ -type f -name '*.md'); do 
            if [ ! -z "$(grep " $output " $f)" ]; then
                open -a /Applications/TextWrangler.app $f 
            fi
        done

done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat ./search-list.txt |  while read output
do

    for f in $(find ./content/ -type f -name '*.md'); do 
        if [ ! -z "$(grep -e "title:[[:space:]]$output[[:space:]]" $f)" ]; then
            open -a /Applications/TextWrangler.app $f 
        fi
    done

done
```

Comment: Any reason you don't like `while read -r output; do ... done <./search-list.txt`? (e.g. `cat file | read` is a *UUOc* - Unnecessary Use Of `cat`)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

`script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat ./search-list.txt |  while read output
  do
    for f in $(find ./content/ -type f -name '*.md'); do
      if echo $f | grep -q $output; then
        echo "opening matched file" $f
        open -a /Applications/TextWrangler.app $f 
      fi
    done
  done
```

Output of `script.sh`:

```
$ cat search-list.txt 
  3.1.3.2
  3.1.4.2
  4.1.3.1
  4.1.4.1
  4.1.5.1
  4.2.1.1
  4.2.2.1
  5.1.6.1

$ touch test1_3.1.3.2_file.md
$ touch test2_3.1.4.2_file.md
$ touch test3_4.1.3.1.md

$./script.sh
opening matched file ./test1_3.1.3.2_file.md
opening matched file ./test2_3.1.4.2_file.md
opening matched file ./test3_4.1.3.1.md
```

Comment: I see that the search list is being passed to the grep, but the file never opens in TextWrangler.

Comment: If you add an `echo $f` after the if, no files match.

Comment: I guess more precisely, I am trying to find: `title: 3.1.3.2` in the file and 3.1.3.2 should be replaced with each entry in the search-list.txt.

Comment: @Claud _"If you add an echo $f after the if, no files match"_. They match for me. I added `echo "opening matched file" $f` after the `if` in the above answer and do see matching files. See updated answer above.